# Whatsapp audio share

Tags: android, android-studio

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://haydo.kufurbaz.kfrbazhaydosesleri/raw/oylemikesiliramk.wav");
            Intent myınIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            myınIntent.setType("audio / wav");
            String sharebody = ".mp3";
            myınIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uri);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(myınIntent,"Share using"));
            return true;
```

When i try to send someone audio to whatsapp it does not shown in format of wav or mp3 it

my file name in raw is : oylemikesiliramk.wav

help pls

Comment: try with myınIntent.setType("audio/*");

Comment: tried but didnt worked